# Using the phase side of the line as ground for an isolated dc/dc converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, mains, isolation

[This evaluation board](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/51567b.pdf) mention connecting the GND of the board to the phase side of the line in order to use a shunt to measure current from the high side. In this example they use a capacitive power supply.

[image]
[image]

Could it be possible to use an isolated DC/DC converter in the same fashion, connecting the 0V to the line ?

[image]

CY being a class Y high voltage capacitor (1nF, 5kV) for EMC compliance.